# Bluetooth A2DP SINK in Mac OS X?

Tags: android, windows, macos, bluetooth

A2DP SINK is used to stream device audio (My Android Phone) to the other (My PC) via bluetooth.

I know there are solutions for Windows 10 2004+.

- [bluetooth-audio-receiver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/bluetooth-audio-receiver/9n9wclwdqs5j?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) on Microsoft Store
- [AudioPlaybackConnector](https://github.com/ysc3839/AudioPlaybackConnector) on Github

My question is: Is there a corresponding solution on Mac OS X? I searched a lot of keywords, but no answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of a complicated topic. As far as I know Apple does not directly allow enabling A2DP sink through Core Bluetooth framework. A possible solution (that I have not tested myself) is using logic similar to https://github.com/airander/A2DP-SINK. Please note the repository is archived.